# MissingSchemaError while using Mongoose Populate with only one model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

**I have answered below. In short you need to require the Model in the module in which you wish to populate, even though you do not refer to it directly.

I am hitting a strange problem with mongoose when populating just one particular array of IDs.

I have three models, User, Company and Widgets.

When I return the company populated with the users all is fine using:

```
Company.findOne({ name: 'xyz' })
    .populate('users')
    .exec(function(err, company) {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
    res.send(company)
    })
```

However when I try to replace populate 'users' with 'widgets' I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"widget\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)",
    "name": "MissingSchemaError"
}
```

Here are the models:

USER:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    company: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'company'
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

COMPANY:

```
const CompanySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    URL: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    users: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    }],
    widgets: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'widget'
    }]
});

const Company = mongoose.model('company', CompanySchema);
```

WIDGET:

```
const WidgetSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    maker: String
});

const Widget = mongoose.model('widget', WidgetSchema);
```

I have manually inspected the _ids in the widget array of the company model and they are all correct.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this was a lack of understanding on my behalf.

In the module where I was using:

```
Company.findOne({ name: 'xyz' })
    .populate('users')
    .exec(function(err, company) {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
    res.send(company)
    })
```

I had imported the User model for other uses in the module. However, as I was not directly referring to Widget I had not imported it. Having done some more research I found that you need to import a model when populating even though not referring to it directly.

Let me know if best to delete whole thread or leave for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really strange. I have spend hours trying to get past this issue